# How to GET two models in one web api controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

So I have two tables in my db, engineer and engineerSettings. I currently have a controller for both api/username and api/userSettings, but I also want to have a controller api/userInformation that returns everything in username as well as userSettings. I'm not really sure how to go about doing this, but right now I have a new model for userInformation

```
public class userInformation
{
    public virtual ICollection<Username> Usernames {get;set;}
    punlic virtual ICollection<UserSetting> UserSettings {get;set;}
}
```

And in my UserInformation controller I have

```
.... 
//GET
public IEnumerable<UserInformation> GetUserInformation()
{
    return db.UserInformations;
}
```

Which doesn't really work so I was wondering how to solve this problem?

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: I'm getting an entity type UserInformation is not part of the model for the current context error, and I have tried adding `modelBuilder.Entity<UserInformation>().ToTable("UserInformation")` to my dbcontext, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Look in your context class. It has to be defined to use it.

Comment: Yes I already defined it, `public virtual DbSet<UserSetting> UserSettings { get; set; }`

Comment: 'UserSettings' is not 'UserInformations'

Comment: Ah Copied and pasted the wrong one, it was mean to be UserInformations not UserSettings

Comment: FWIW, Visual Studio (if that's what you're using) offers a couple of straight-forward methods to troubleshoot your code. They've been very helpful in finding solutions to questions not found in SO. The first one involves right-clicking on the far left of the code line for the method that's not working, and running it in local debug, your VS needs to be configured for symbols. The second method involves creating a .TESTS project, referencing your main project and adding the methods as [TestMethod] you will sometimes get much more detailed error info then on your browser. HTH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fill your model:

```
public UserInformation GetUserInformation()
{
        UserInformation UserInfo= new UserInformation();
        List<Username> lstUsername= new List<Username>();
        List<UserSetting> lstUserSetting= new List<UserSetting>();
        lstUserSetting=db.UserSettings.ToList();
        lstUsername=db.Usernames.ToList();
        UserInfo.Usernames =lstUsername;
        UserInfo.UserSettings =lstUserSetting;
        return UserInfo;
}
```

Comment: Yess. Thank you! I knew it wasn't as straightforward as I thought. :)

Comment: How would I say, if Usernames and usersetting both share an "Id", how do i only return the usernames and usersetting of that Id?

Comment: for selecting single user with userID `db.Usernames.Where(m => m.ID == userID).FirstOrDefault();`